# Не работает кеширование wp-super-cache

Tags: php, wordpress, кэширование, wp-plugin

После обновления плагина **wp-super-cache** с версии 1.6.1  до 1.6.2 перестал работать кеш страниц, в которых есть частичная подгрузка данных со сторонего сервиса: **wp_remote_get()**,
То есть на другие страницы серверный кеш отлично работает, а в которых есть **wp_remote_get** такое ощущение, что отправляет этот запрос каждый раз, а потом отдает кешированую страницу, как быть, куда двигаться, может у кого-то похожее что-то было?

Comment: В плагине есть опция (в Расширенных настройках) - "Включить динамическое кеширование". В ней ссылка на FAQ и код примера. Попробуйте, возможно, поможет.

Comment: Пофиксил через get_transient, set_transient.